# Custom colormap for fill3 function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, colors, fill

Basically I'm trying to make a visualization of a 2D finite element solution on a mesh of triangular elements. So I'm going triangle by triangle and using the fill3 function to plot it. Right now I'm doing

```
% K is the number of mesh elements

for i=1:K
    % x,y,z are 3x1 vectors of the x,y,and z coordinates of the triangle vertices respectively
    fill3(x,y,z,gradient(z))
end
```

The problem with this is that for each INDIVIDUAL triangle, using the gradient(z) colormap means the smallest value of z on the current triangle corresponds to the minimum and maximum value of z corresponds to the maximum.

What I'd like is for there to be some consistency for the colormap across ALL of the triangles, much like when you use the 'surf' function. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can normalize by the global maximum value of the triangles in the `fill3` line. So, for each triangle, compute gradient(z) and find both it's max and min value. collect all these values, find the **global** max and min values. Denote these values as `gmax`, `gmin`, then we can normalize the entire data set according to these values.  For example

```
 fill3(x,y,z, (gradient(z)-gmin)/(gmax-gmin) )
```

this should take all gradient values and map them to the interval [0,1] for all triangles. Then the colormaps should be consistent among triangles.

Comment: hmm, I understand the reasoning behind that. So for each triangle, compute gradient(z) and find its max. then compare among all triangles to find the maximum value of the 'local' maxes? I tried implementing that and got some weird results for the colorscale